# Database structure for ranged values

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

I am trying to implement a table where I can use it for filtering,
the table must contain for example Age (From,To) Gender (Male,Female,All)
Education (Computer,Software,Engineer) ... etc

so regarding the database structure, is it good to use json ? will this makes it hard for the filtering ?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing about your data which would necessarily make me think that you need to use JSON.  Why are you thinking of storing JSON data?

Comment: I have around 20 filters and some of them ranged (from to) and some are multiple, I think its not good idea to store multiple columns for (from,to) or pivot table for the multiple filters such as education, so maybe if I store json object will be easier ?

Comment: If you store your data as JSON then at least a portion of it will be denormalized, which will make it difficult or impossible to use an index.  If you want rapid queries then try to avoid JSON, CSV,  etc.  This is my opinion.

Comment: You might have a table of age_ranges,  (age_range_id, range_start,range_end)

Comment: You might also look at CHECK constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In the programming world this types should be Enum. so how enums will be implemented in a relational database?

create a table for each enum type (such as gender), each table just has two columns: data and foreign key. data is the value for enum (such as male, female, all) and foreign keys could be a desired value.

anywhere a type (table) needs  an enum just use the foreign key there.

Comment: Thank you amin, and regarding the from to columns ?

Comment: you can use this approach for that too. just consider each age range as a row in a separate table. but if you want exact age with a max an min value the story would differ.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you! but with respect i can't accept this. i don't agree on "enums usually are evils" and i can argue about that.

Comment: @Amin As long as the OP is appraised of the evidence, then they're free to make up their own mind, right?